# Quadratic number field which is Euclidean but not norm Euclidean

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory

> I am looking for an example of a quadratic field $\mathbb Q[\sqrt d]$ , with $d \equiv 2 $ or $3\pmod 4$ , whose ring of integers is Euclidean but not [norm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_norm) Euclidean.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is incomplete: http://oeis.org/wiki/Euclidean_domain The ones with question marks are where I would (or I will) start looking.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen : That is not much helpful , I am asking for Euclidean evaluations which are not field norms ( i.e. not even absolute value of field norms ) where as the thread concentrates on real Euclidean domains not valuations

Comment: You're right, Saun Dev. I was fairly sure that an example has been posted here (or at MO) earlier. I've been looking for it for about 8 minutes. That was just a placeholder :-) My recollection was that $d=23$ is a counterexample, and my searching had reached [this](http://mathoverflow.net.80bola.com/questions/51503/a-question-about-non-norm-euclidean-real-quadratic-fields?rq=1), when Gerry's answer came.

Comment: Saun Dev, I found [a better local link](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/63859/11619).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen : Thanks , the wiki link there in the first answer really helped , I finally got a positive answer that imaginary quadratic field , if is Euclidean , then is norm Euclidean .

Comment: The boilerplate "your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level." really doesn't apply to a question like this, which is more along the lines of a reference request than a do-my homework-for-me quesiton. I'm voting to reopen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See M. Harper, *${\bf Z}[\sqrt{14}]$ is Euclidean*, Canad. J. Math. Vol. 56 (2004), 55–70, available [here](http://cms.math.ca/openaccess/cjm/v56/harper2205.pdf). It's also done in Bernhard Lutzmann, *Quadratic number fields that are Euclidean but not norm-Euclidean*, available [here](http://thales.doa.fmph.uniba.sk/macaj/skola/atc/LutzmannDipl.pdf). Also worth a look is Malcolm Harper and M. Ram Murty, *Euclidean rings of algebraic integers*, Canad. J. Math. Vol. 56 (1), 2004 pp. 71–76, available [here](http://www.math.purdue.edu/~lipman/553/Harper-Murty.pdf).

Comment: @SaunDev This is a good answer but an even better answer would give a Euclidean domain *and* its associated Euclidean function. See this question from a couple of months ago: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1148364/what-is-the-euclidean-function-for-mathbbz-sqrt14 The only answer so far says this ring is Euclidean but not norm-Euclidean and that its Euclidean function *can* be obtained. Apparently it's way more involved than the simple adjustment to the norm required for $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{69})}$ (yeah, I know $69 \equiv 1 \bmod 4$).