# Is there another proof of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-6}]$ being not a UFD?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I found out that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-6}]$ is not euclidean and all proofs I saw used a pretty simple idea: to show that this ring is not UFD, however they all used norm $\mathcal{N}(a+b\sqrt{-6}) = a^2+6b^2$. But why one can assume the norm to be such? Is there another way to prove?

Comment: This is the definition of the norm on a quadratic field.

Comment: Sure; you could show directly that each of $2$, $3$, and $\sqrt{-6}$ are irreducible, by showing that $(a+b\sqrt{-6})(c+d\sqrt{-6})=2$, for example, has no nontrivial solutions. The norm just makes showing that easier. Once you know they are all irreducible, you also need to verify that the only units are $1$ and $-1$, again by looking at $(a+b\sqrt{-6})(r+s\sqrt{-6})=1$; and then noting that $(2)(3)=(-1)(\sqrt{6})^2$.

Comment: Once you have the definition of the norm and have verified its properties, that makes life easier. There is an intermediate step in learning where the ideas are motivated, and this is one of the examples that can be used either to motivate, or to illustrate, the more general idea. The status of the example depends on whether it is "motivation" or "illustration" and that depends on the exposition you are following.

Comment: Not wanting to use the norm is analogous to proving a matrix is not invertible without using the determinant (the analogy is very close, considering the norm mapping *is* a determinant from a certain point of view).  For most people, using the determinant is a very natural way to look at multiplicative questions about matrices, and likewise using the norm is a very natural way to start looking at multiplicative questions in $\mathbf Z[\sqrt{-6}]$.

Comment: @KCd I was just confused with such an assumption, because there is no formula for norm in definition. So using particular norm in order to show that ring is not euclidean seems strange to me.

Comment: Not only does use of norm maps often "make life easier" as @KCd hints, but there are in fact rigorous characterizations of how factorization (divisor) theory in (quadratic) number rings is related to that in their monoid of norms, e.g. in some favorable contexts (e.g. Galois) a number ring enjoys unique factorization iff its monoid of norms does - see the papers I [cite here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/95015/242). For further examples along the lines of the OP see the [posts where I cite such](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A242+bumby)

Comment: Even if norms are not in the definition of a UFD (and not all rings have a "norm" function like the norm on $\mathbf Z[\sqrt{-6}]$), that norm is there whether you want to use it or not. Many concepts in math are developed in the context of solving problems where those concepts are not part of the statement of the problem. Rather than consider it strange to solve a problem using methods not initially appearing in the problem, consider it a reason that such methods were originally created. Norms are *good*: they move you multiplicatively from an unfamiliar system to a more familiar one.

Comment: **Beware** that the answer you accepted does not make it clear that it uses results that typically are not known at the point where exercises like this are often posed in introductory treatments on quadratic number rings. If you seek answers at such introductory level then it would be a good idea to unaccept so that others will see your question (many readers skip questions that already have accepted answers). We  already have many prior answers at this level on this and related topics - which can be located by searching.

Comment: Which definition of "norm" are you using?

Comment: By the way, for motivation, you might find it helpful to view the use of norms here as a special case of the [method of simpler multiples](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3224776/242), which I mention briefly there (along with many other examples).

Comment: Any thoughts on any of the answers that have been posted, Egor?

Comment: It's not polite, Egor, to post a question and then refuse to engage with the users who try to help you.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson, I did not refuse. As for the problem, I think that I confused norm and a square of modulus while reading some proofs...

Comment: The norm *is* the square of the modulus, in ${\bf Z}[\sqrt{-6}]$. Anyway, if you found one of the three answers particularly helpful, you have the option of "accepting" it, by clicking in the check mark next to it.

Answer (score 4):

From what I read into your question you are asking "why do we show that $\mathcal N(a+b\sqrt{-6})=a^2+6b^2$ is not an euclidean valuation" while we *should* prove that "there is no euclidean valuation at all". Or at least that is part of the question how to show that $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-6}]$ is not an UFD.

To understand this we should take a step back and consider more generally quadratic extensions of $\mathbb Q$ of the form $\mathbb Q(\sqrt d)$ for some (squarefree) integer $d$. And then we note that *every* such extension field has a very natural associated norm function; namely $\mathcal N(a+b\sqrt d)=a^2-b^2d$. This function has some every desirable properties (for example it is valued entirely in $\mathbb Q$, the base field, and it is multiplicative).
In fact, if you know some Galois theory, this is *the* norm defined as product over all conjugates under the Galois group action. The conjugates of $a+b\sqrt d$ are in our case simply given by $a+b\sqrt d$ and $a-b\sqrt d$ whose product is precisely $a^2-b^2d$. So to define $\mathcal N(a+b\sqrt d)=a^2-b^2d$ is, indeed, a very, very natural thing.

Thus, every quadratic extension field comes with a norm function. We can even restrict this function to $\mathbb Z[\sqrt d]$ to examine this associated ring. Interestingly enough, this function turns out to actually be euclidean for specific values (for exampe $d=-2,-3$). But this does not hold in general ($d=-19$ is a notable counterexample altough we consider a slightly different ring then). In general this norm function is "just" a useful tool for examing the rings $\mathbb Z[\sqrt d]$. As and such tool it is typically used when showing that $\mathbb Z[\sqrt d]$ is not an UFD.

For example, you can show that an element $\alpha\in\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-6}]$ is a unit if and only if $\mathcal N(\alpha)\in\{\pm1\}$. Moreover, using this, you can show that an element whose norm is a prime integer has to be irreducible. This can then be applied to show that some elements in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-6}]$ admit different factorizations into irreducibles, which is impossible in an UFD.

Answer (score 3):

For a person whose only background is abstract algebra, say a first course involving rings, there is very little technique available so you can't do much other than give a direct example of non-unique irreducible factorization. For someone farther along in their studies, there are other methods.  Here is one such method.

Using concepts from algebraic number theory (Dedekind domains), it can be shown that *if* a quadratic ring $\mathbf Z[\sqrt{d}]$ is a UFD then it must be a PID, so finding a non-principal ideal in $\mathbf Z[\sqrt{-6}]$ proves this ring is not a UFD. (Be careful: many UFDs are not PIDs, like $\mathbf Z[x]]$, so it's very important that it's possible to prove quadratic rings can be UFDs if and only if they are PIDs first!)

Let
$$
I = (2,\sqrt{-6}) = \mathbf Z 2 + \mathbf Z\sqrt{-6}.
$$
That last equation is not a definition, but instead has to be proved: $I$ is defined to be the *ideal* generated by $2$ and $\sqrt{-6}$, so in principle you should be allowing coefficients in $\mathbf Z[\sqrt{-6}]$ and therefore it requires a proof that the $\mathbf Z$-linear combinations of $2$ and $\sqrt{-6}]$ already give you everything in the ideal. In any case, since $\mathbf Z[\sqrt{-6}] = \mathbf Z + \mathbf Z\sqrt{-6}$, the ideal $I$ has index 2 inside $\mathbf Z[\sqrt{-6}]$ (as abelian groups). To prove $I$ is not principal, it turns out that the index of a nonzero principal ideal $(a+b\sqrt{-6})$ inside $\mathbf  Z[\sqrt{-6}]$ is $a^2 + 6b^2$ (oh look, there's the norm!) and since $a^2 + 6b^2$ is never 2 for integers $a$ and $b$, no principal ideal has index $2$ and thus $I$ is not a principal ideal.

Comment: But this surely uses many results the OP does not yet have available. while there are much simpler proofs that avoid such, So it is a bit **misleading pedagogically** to post an answer like this (esp, without linking to proofs of your many unjustified claims so that the OP can easily see that they are beyond their knowledge).

Comment: I said right near the start "For someone farther along in their studies, there are other methods."  So I disagree that my post was misleading.  At the same time, I was surprised the OP gave my answer a check mark so quickly.

Comment: Likely they accepted because it isn't necessarily clear from what you have written that you are actually using said "other methods" in what follows, and that these are methods beyond what is usually taught in (brief) introductions to quadratic number fields (likely the source of most such questions on this site).

Answer (score 0):

It is possible for the integers in a quadratic number field to be Euclidean but not "norm-Euclidean"; see, e.g., [Quadratic number field which is Euclidean but not norm Euclidean](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1234305/quadratic-number-field-which-is-euclidean-but-not-norm-euclidean). BUT if you can show that the integers are not a UFD then you have shown that the ring is not Euclidean (since, if it's Euclidean, it is *a fortiori* a UFD), and there's nothing wrong with using the norm to prove it's not a UFD. You're not making any assumption about the ring being norm-Euclidean, you're just using the norm as a tool to prove it's not a UFD.